# Handle errors in a reusable fetch function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a reusable fetch function (that's going to live in a separate file) and I am not too sure about the best approach to handle a function returning a null.

Say I am want to call that function and apply some logic when `getOrganizationInfo` doesn't return organization info. At the moment my function returns an error but falls into the first `if (organization)` block and I can't really handle that. I then need to use that error message to use it in the handleSubmit e.g. `showError(error)`. What shall I do to take advantage of this `else` logic?

```
const orgName = 'ABC';

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const organization = await getOrganizationInfo(orgName);
  
  if (organization) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Here's my function

```
export const getOrganizationInfo = async (
  organizationName: string,
): Promise<OrganizationInfoResponse> => {
  let organizationInfoResponse: OrganizationInfoResponse;

  try {
    const rawRes = await fetch(`/sometestendpoint/${organizationName}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    organizationInfoResponse = await rawRes.json();

    if (rawRes.status >= 400) {
      if (organizationInfoResponse.errorCode === ErrorCodes.INVALID_ORG_NAME) {
        throw new Error('Given Organization Name is invalid');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to get organization information.');
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // organizationInfoResponse = error.toString();
    throw new Error(error.toString());
  }

  return organizationInfoResponse;
};
```

Comment: *"At the moment my function returns an error but falls into the first if (organization) block"*: the code you have shared does not do that. If `getOrganizationInfo` throws an error, then the promise that `handleSubmit` returned will reject, without execution of the `if...else` block.

Comment: Maybe I have described it incorrectly. `organizationInfoResponse = error.toString();` in the catch block does return a string which falls into the `if` true block. Either way none of the options give a desired result. I am trying my best for it to go to the else if there's an error.

Comment: Falling into the `if` block? It is not possible that that happens here: when the `catch` block executes, you are throwing an error there -- not returning a value. By consequence the `await` in `handleSubmit` will prevent further code execution in `handleSubmit`. Nor the `if`, nor the `else` is executed in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The code as provided in your question will do the following when it gets into the `catch` block:

- It executes `throw new Error(error.toString())`
- The promise in the following expression will reject: `await getOrganizationInfo(orgName)`
- The promise that was returned by `handleSubmit` will reject
- None of the code in `handleSubmit` that follows below this `await` will execute

So what you claim to happen is not happening. Maybe you were talking about the version of your code where the `catch` block did not have that `throw`, but had the commented line instead:

```
catch (error) {
    organizationInfoResponse = error.toString();
}
```

In that case the code will "fall into the `if`", because then the error is swallowed by the above `catch` block:

- The function continues with `return organizationInfoResponse`
- The promise in the following expression will fulfill: `await getOrganizationInfo(orgName)`
- The function execution context of `handleSubmit` is restored and `organization` is assigned the fulfilment value (i.e. `error.toString()`)
- The `if (organization)` condition is truthy, and so the `if` block executes

#### Solution

To get the `else` block executed, use the `throw` version of your code, and either introduce a `try...catch` block in `handleSubmit`, or (simpler) chain a `.then` and `.catch` call on the promise:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  return getOrganizationInfo(orgName).then(organisation => {
    if (!organisation) throw new Error("Organisation is falsy");
    // Do something

  }).catch(error => {
    // Do something else

  });
}
```